# Rendering Math in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mathjax

I am trying to Render Math Equation in a React Component with MathJax. It actually worked well if I pre-render it within the HTML file, but it is a mess when i try rendering it in React.

Here's my code

```
class Latex extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount(){
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)]);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)]);
}

render() {
    //dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.children}}
    return (
         <h5 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.children}}></h5>
    );
}
}
```

[Math Display both in Regular HTML and React Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33vsD.png)

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question. What does "it is a mess" mean? Be specific.

Comment: As in the messy rendering in the screenshot I attached. Each equation character stand-alone on a line(like a block element)

Comment: It would be a lot easier to debug this if you could reproduce the problem in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). At any rate, one issue is that the `__html` property of the object passed to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` should be a string, but `this.props.children` will be an array of React components.

Comment: As @Ansjovis86 says, most packages are poorly maintained. I therefore wrote my own, using latest React with hooks API. Check it out: [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax). It is highly configurable and doesn't require any additional packages (except React). The docs contain plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh no, I was so disappointed in myself when I found out what I was doing wrong. I applied display of Block to the Span element that renders the Latex (My take was that it would treat the whole chunk as one) and it put each Equation character onto a separate line. Changing the display to "inline" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I used a combination of [algebra.js](http://algebra.js.org) and [react-mathjax](https://github.com/wko27/react-mathjax) libraries to get it working in ES6. Because all these other packages are poorly maintained. For react-mathjax please use this [repo](https://github.com/wko27/react-mathjax).

Here's an example for showing fractions:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fraction, toTex } from 'algebra.js';
import { Node, Context } from 'react-mathjax';

function Formula(props) {
  return (
    <Context input="tex">
      <Node inline>{props.tex}</Node>
    </Context>
  );
}

export default function FractionDisplay() {
  const a = new Fraction(1, 5);
  const b = new Fraction(2, 7);
  const answer = a.multiply(b);

  const question = <Formula tex={`${toTex(a)} × ${toTex(b)} = ${toTex(answer)}`} />;

  return (
    <div>
      {question}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In NPM, this package is called `react-mathjax2`. When I tried to use it in React 16, I ended up with a completely blank screen. That is, none of my other previous content was rendered. However, `react-mathjax` (SamyPesse) works for me.

Comment: @RyanH. You just saved me so much time. Thank you for your comment. I could not for the life of me figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Been a couple years, but if anyone is looking for a functional + mathjax3 based approach there is this repo:

https://github.com/jpribyl/react-hook-mathjax

demo of it is available at https://johnpribyl.com/react-hook-mathjax/

Usage is like this:

#### Basic inline display

```
import React from "react";
import Tex2SVG from "react-hook-mathjax";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Tex2SVG display="inline" latex="e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Customizing MathJax options

```
import React from "react";
import Tex2SVG, { MathJaxProvider } from "react-hook-mathjax";

// This object contains the default options, more info at:
// http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output/svg.html 
const mathJaxOptions = {
  svg: {
    scale: 1,                      // global scaling factor for all expressions
    minScale: .5,                  // smallest scaling factor to use
    mtextInheritFont: false,       // true to make mtext elements use surrounding font
    merrorInheritFont: true,       // true to make merror text use surrounding font
    mathmlSpacing: false,          // true for MathML spacing rules, false for TeX rules
    skipAttributes: {},            // RFDa and other attributes NOT to copy to the output
    exFactor: .5,                  // default size of ex in em units
    displayAlign: 'center',        // default for indentalign when set to 'auto'
    displayIndent: '0',            // default for indentshift when set to 'auto'
    fontCache: 'local',            // or 'global' or 'none'
    localID: null,                 // ID to use for local font cache (for single equation processing)
    internalSpeechTitles: true,    // insert <title> tags with speech content
    titleID: 0                     // initial id number to use for aria-labeledby titles
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MathJaxProvider options={mathJaxOptions} />
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Tex2SVG display="inline" latex="e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0" />
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Parsing user input

```
import React from "react";
import Tex2SVG from "react-hook-mathjax";

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(
    "G_{\\mu\\nu} + \\Lambda g_{\\mu\\nu} = \\kappa T_{\\mu\\nu}",
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>React Hook MathJax</h3>
        <input
          type="text"
          defaultValue={inputValue}
          onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />

        <div className="tex-container">
          <Tex2SVG class="tex" tabindex={-1} latex={inputValue} />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Handling error states

```
import React from "react";
import Tex2SVG from "react-hook-mathjax";

const getErrorFromHTML = (html) =>
  html.children[1].firstChild.firstChild.attributes["data-mjx-error"].value;

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(
    "G_{\\mu\\nu} + \\Lambda g_{\\mu\\nu} = \\kappa T_{\\mu\\nu}",
  );
  const [lastValidInput, setLastValidInput] = React.useState("");
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const hasError = error !== null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>React Hook MathJax</h3>
        <input
          className={`${hasError ? "error" : ""}`}
          type="text"
          defaultValue={inputValue}
          onChange={e => {
            setInputValue(e.target.value);
            setError(null);
          }}
        />

        <div className="tex-container">
          <Tex2SVG
            class="tex"
            tabindex={-1}
            latex={hasError ? lastValidInput : inputValue}
            onSuccess={() =>
              setLastValidInput(hasError ? lastValidInput : inputValue)
            }
            onError={html => setError(getErrorFromHTML(html))}
          />
        </div>
    {hasError && <div>hint: {error}</div>}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### API

#### `MathJaxProvider` props:

##### `options` Object, optional

- Sets [MathJax configuration](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/index.html?highlight=hub.config#configuration-objects).
- Default: Official MathJax configuration

#### `Tex2SVG` props:

##### `latex` string, required

- The string which is passed to MathJax for conversion. Must be valid ![LaTeX](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/LaTeX_logo.svg/800px-LaTeX_logo.svg.png =50x) in order for a successful conversion into an `svg`
- Default: `''`

##### `onSuccess` (HTMLElement) => void, optional

- Triggered after a successful conversion of LaTeX string into an `svg` - it receives the html object generated by MathJax
- Default: `(html: HTMLElement) => {}`

##### `onError` (HTMLElement) => void, optional

- Triggered after a failed conversion of LaTeX string into an `svg` - it receives the html object generated by MathJax
- Default: `(html: HTMLElement) => {}`

##### `Other html attributes`  {[key: string]: any} optional

- All other props passed into this component will be directly translated onto the DOM node
- This allows you to add css classes or other handlers, see usage examples above
- NOTE: this does not attach to the virtual DOM, so pass `class` - not `className` etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30985350)

Comment: added usage notes from the readme

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good but this is not the way react works. Instead of using MathJax why you don't use [react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax) or [react-formula-beautifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-formula-beautifier). And use them just like another component (which is how react is intended to work).

[Here](https://github.com/SamyPesse/react-mathjax/blob/master/example/main.js) you have the oficial example.

**Advise:** If you want to use some lib in react, try to search react-nameoflib. Most libraries have his react version.

Comment: I tried the react-mathjax as well, it still renders as in the screenshot I attached.

Comment: Try to style it on the browser with the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks, re-styling it was exactly what I needed to do.

Comment: I'm glad you finally found a solution. :)

Comment: Anyone know of a @types lib for mathjax-react. I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this before the Component class `declare var MathJax;`. It should work seamlessly.